# how can I find a specific value in a arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of a list that I'm being passed over as data.  The example they gave was the object will look like this:

```
List assetClassCorrelationMatrix = new ArrayList();
List m1 = new ArrayList();
m1.add(2);
m1.add(4);
m1.add(0.8979);
assetClassCorrelationMatrix.add(m1);
```

EDIT:  OK, so I'm sorry I was not clear.
I was thinking that this was going to be in the structure of

```
correlation[2][4] = 0.8979
```

Instead they are giving me:

```
correlation[0] = 2;
correlation[1] = 4;
correlation[2] = 0.8979;
```

I just need to get back whatever is in `correlation[2]` when I just have the values of what is in `correlation[0]` and `correlation[1]`

Help?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "to iterate thru the arraylist using the first two values"?

Comment: What do you mean iterate through the `ArrayList` **using the first two values to get the 3rd**? The first two values have nothing to do with the 3rd value in the list. Iterating the list should be no different from the first two and you can get it using index `2`. I think you may need to clarify what exactly it is you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need other values for finding a specific value in nested arraylist.  If you are looking for a specific value in arraylist `assetClassCorrelationMatrix`, you can do this way:

```
double num = 0.8979;        
for (Object object: assetClassCorrelationMatrix) {            
    List list = (List) object;                                    
    if(list.contains(num))
        System.out.println("The number " + num + " is found at index =  " + list.indexOf(num));
}
```

**Edit:** After you edited question, it seems radical change of context. Now you have two value (like index value 2 and 4 in 2D array) and you want to get the value of the index. You could do this using 2D array easily. But if you want to stick with list, you could go this way:

```
    List assetClassCorrelationMatrix = new ArrayList();

    int a=2, b=4;

    List m1 = new ArrayList();
    List m2 = new ArrayList();        

    // inserting values
    m2.add(0, 1.1); 
    m2.add(1, 2.0);
    m2.add(2, 0.5);
    m2.add(3, 0.8979);

    assetClassCorrelationMatrix.add(m1);
    assetClassCorrelationMatrix.add(m2);

    List list = (List) assetClassCorrelationMatrix.get(a-1);
    Number number = (Number) list.get(b-1);
    System.out.println("List = " + a + " and index = " + b + " and the number = " + number);
```

Comment: It's not that I'm looking to "find" 0.8979, I need to be able to find it where the other two values are 2 and 4.

Comment: `" I need to get back the 0.8979 value from the arraylist. I already have the values 2 and 4."` and `"I need to be able to find it where the other two values are 2 and 4."` ..... which is true?

Comment: Not sure I follow where you're going with the get(a-1) or get(b-1).  The values 2 and 4 are just what they passed me.. It could of just as well been 3,7,-0.0847.  It probably shows that I'm not a java programmer.

Comment: You want value at index 2,4,3,7 etc which is ok. but how could it be -0.0847??

Comment: I royally messed up the wording of this question because I was not certain how to phrase it.  Knew what I wanted, just not how to say it.  I don't want the value AT the index, I want the index.
boolean corr1 = mat.get(0).equals(outerAssetClassID);
boolean corr2 = mat.get(1).equals(innerAssetClassID);
if(corr1&&corr2) double correlation = (double)mat.get(2);
I got it figured... took me 10hrs but.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Start by specifying properly the type of your lists, it should be something like this:

```
List<List<Number>> assetClassCorrelationMatrix = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> m1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can access to your value `0.8979` using [List#get(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-), like this:

```
Number n = m1.get(2); // The indexes start from 0, so the index of the 3th element is 2
```

If you want to access it from `assetClassCorrelationMatrix`, it would be:

```
Number n = assetClassCorrelationMatrix.get(0).get(2);
```

You can identify this value among the other by checking the type, indeed `2` and `4` will be converted automatically as `Integer` due to auto-boxing and `0.8979` as `Double`.

```
for (Number n : m1) {
    if (n instanceof Double) {
        // Here is the code that treats the Double value
    }
}
```